# Are all licensed and published Battletech novels considered canon?

Tags: canon, battletech

Are all professional Battletech novels also part of the official Battletech canon? The two works of whose canon status I'm not certain are "Far Country" and "No Limits", since they ignore fundamental premises of the Battletech universe. Additionally, I'm not sure, if novels which were first published by non-English publishers are considered canon.

Comment: what's a 'professional novel'?  Do you mean published?

Comment: I mean non-fanfic, any books by publishers having the license to publish Battletech novels. This includes non-English first publications as well.

Comment: I edited to echo your response.  Feel free to edit your own question back if you feel I redirected your intent, and apologies if so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This site](http://www.sarna.net/wiki/Main_Page) is pretty clear on Battletech canon.  I won't post the [whole article on 'Canon'](http://www.sarna.net/wiki/Canon) here, but a relevant excerpt:

> **Whatever we establish for research material for the authors is canon.**
> Currently, that list includes:
>
> All sourcebooks and novels produced for BattleTech by FASA and Roc in
> the United States
>
> All sourcebooks and novels produced for Classic BattleTech by FanPro
> and Roc in the United States
>
> All sourcebooks and novels (including electronic publications, such as
> BattleCorps) produced by InMediaRes (and its subsidiaries, BattleCorps
> and Catalyst Game Labs) in the United States
>
> All material produced by WizKids for the MechWarrior: Dark
> Age/MechWarrior: Age of Destruction game lines
>
> GENERAL INCLUSIVE NOTE: There are a few select instances where a story
> or article appearing even in these sources may be considered
> non-canon, but generally this is because the material was in error
> [...], or it was specifically published as a gag [...].

The same site actually specifically says which books are canon and which are not on their individual articles.  **It appears *[Far Country](http://www.sarna.net/wiki/Far_Country)* is, and *[No Limits](http://www.sarna.net/wiki/No_Limits)* is not.**

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Considering-non-English novels I've just found the answer [here](http://www.sarna.net/wiki/Novels#Original_German_Language_BattleTech_books).

Comment: @schlossblick Yep, the site is evidently the go-to for Battletech.

Comment: Before I go on to the next life, I wither want a sequel to Far Country or to find out the eventual canon fate of Clan Wolverine!